# GWT Moving a custom widget-Composite

Tags: gwt, widget

I have a Composite which I will place in an Absolute Panel, I want to be able to specify the location coordinates of the composite and place it at that location in the absolute panel.

Also, at run time, sometime I will have to change the location coordinates of the Composite and move it.

I could have use a grid or other panel but while moving the composit, I want to place a move animation, that's why I'm using an absolute panel.

How to specify the coordinates of the composite before placing it in the absolute panel?

the composite:

```
public class SlotView extends Composite
{
...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`AbsolutePanel.setWidgetPosition()`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.3/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/AbsolutePanel.html#setWidgetPosition%28com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget,%20int,%20int%29) will change the location of a Widget displayed inside of an `AbsolutePanel`.  This is limited only to using pixel-based offsets.

A more robust solution is to use a [`LayoutPanel`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.3/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/LayoutPanel.html), which supports the use of font- or box-relative positions.  `LayoutPanel` also has support for animating transitions.

Comment: DO u know how can get the top and left of a widget in a Layout panel by doing layoutpanel.getWidget(0)??